# MySQL: very slow query using nested sub-query

Tags: mysql, mysql-dependent-subquery

**QUERY:**

```
 SELECT 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(cleanpoi.ID) FROM cleanpoi
        WHERE cleanpoi.EstablishmentID=parent.ID
    ) AS POIs,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM cleanamenitymappings WHERE CleanPOIID IN 
        (
            SELECT cleanpoi.ID FROM cleanpoi
            WHERE cleanpoi.EstablishmentID=parent.ID
        )
    ) AS Amenities,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM cleanamenityvalues WHERE CleanPOIID IN 
        (
            SELECT cleanpoi.ID FROM cleanpoi
            WHERE cleanpoi.EstablishmentID=parent.ID
        )
    ) AS AmenityValues
    FROM establishment parent
    WHERE parent.ID=3
```

**EXPLAIN RESULT:**

```
 id  select_type         table                 type             possible_keys                              key              key_len  ref       rows  Extra                     
------  ------------------  --------------------  ---------------  -----------------------------------------  ---------------  -------  ------  ------  --------------------------
     1  PRIMARY             parent                const            PRIMARY                                    PRIMARY          4        const        1  Using index               
     5  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  cleanamenityvalues    ALL              (NULL)                                     (NULL)           (NULL)   (NULL)   31778  Using where               
     6  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  cleanpoi              unique_subquery  PRIMARY,EstablishmentID_2,EstablishmentID  PRIMARY          4        func         1  Using where               
     3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  cleanamenitymappings  index            (NULL)                                     CleanPOIID       4        (NULL)  673591  Using where; Using index  
     4  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  cleanpoi              unique_subquery  PRIMARY,EstablishmentID_2,EstablishmentID  PRIMARY          4        func         1  Using where               
     2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  cleanpoi              ref              EstablishmentID_2,EstablishmentID          EstablishmentID  4        const      181
```

Any advice with this query? Your answers are really appreciated!

Comment: To improve performance, remove the nested query or increase your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`

Comment: Why do you post an answer as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers but this solved my problem.

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(cleanpoi.ID) FROM cleanpoi
        WHERE cleanpoi.EstablishmentID=parent.ID
    ) AS POIs,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(a.ID) 
        FROM cleanamenitymappings a LEFT JOIN cleanpoi b ON a.CleanPOIID=b.ID
        WHERE b.EstablishmentID=parent.ID
    ) AS Amenities,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(a.ID) 
        FROM cleanamenityvalues a LEFT JOIN cleanpoi b ON a.CleanPOIID=b.ID
        WHERE b.EstablishmentID=parent.ID
    ) AS AmenityValues
    FROM establishment parent
    WHERE parent.ID=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does scan through 700k rows, all which need to be read from disk. I am guessing on poor disk performance (bandwidth and/or seek time).

If you run this query often, consider creating a materialized view, which is a table holding the answer to the entire query and which you update using triggers when the underlying data changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would create temporary tables with the intermediate results, and then select from this temporary tables.

It might be useful to create a stored procedure to do that:

```
delimiter ;;
create procedure MyLongProcedure()
begin
    -- Just in case, drop the temporary tables before creating them
    drop table if exists temp_step01;
    -- Make a temporary table for each subquery
    create temporary table temp_step01
         select ... ;
    -- Be sure to create the appropriate indexes for each temporary table
    alter table temp_step01
         add index .... ;
    -- Create as much tables as you need
    -- Finally, execute your final query using all the tables you just created
    select ... ;
end;;
delimiter ;
```

Remember: Temporary tables can be read *only* by the connection that created them. In a multi-user environment that can be useful... or not, depending on your specific needs.

This is just an idea. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This might be helpful. I'll try this sooner. I'm still looking at the better solution.